# How to work with objects in a binary file in Python

Tags: python, file, binary, filereader, binaryfiles

I have a binary file with scattered values for different objects.

For example, I have a list of various objects that I have to go over to get the values for each of them. Most are in the pseudo-code documentation where you need if statements, for loops, and class objects. There are more objects, here are just examples:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height, angle):
        self.width = width  # 8 bytes real
        self.heigth = height  # 8 bytes real
        self.angle = angle  # 8 bytes real


class Square:
    def __init__(self, side_length, is_red):
        self.side_length = side_length  # 8 bytes real
        self.is_red = is_red  # 1 bytes, bool
```

At this point, I'm manually calculating where the byte sequence of interest could be, but that's not a good solution:

```
with open('file.ext', 'rb') as file:
    results = file.read()
    buffer_size = int.from_bytes(results[81:85], byteorder='little')
```

I'm asking for advice on how to work better with a binary file.

Comment: Is there a reason you are forced to work with a binary file? Typically there must be some predefined structure for binary files to be of use. And manually skipping forward to where your desired data is in concordance to the format of the binary file should not be an issue. Otherwise if possible consider a more structured data storage approach like JSON?

Comment: @JasonChia Yes, I have been provided with a file that I need to work on. This is the reason. The structure is in the documentation in the form of pseudo code. Manual byte navigation does not always give the desired values.

Comment: There are no header bytes that define what the next bytes are? Normally a binary file will have a header that states what the following bytes mean. I.e header1, data1, header2, data2. If this is not existing how do you know which bytes correspond to which data? Based on your psuedocode you have 8+8+8 bytes and 8+1 bytes for two diffrent classes. How are they separated? Newline? Find the separator then parse iteratively.